# Creating Complex relationships between multiple columns from 2 different tables

Tags: powerbi, relationship

How do we create a relationship between the date and item number from 2 different tables so that when I create graphs it can correctly calculate the sum of how much each item has produced per day. The date and item number need to work in sync when adding it to a graph for either 1st table or 2nd table.
Here is my data :
Table 1:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4DJv.png)
Table 2:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AANdI.png)

I have tried the treatas expression, creating multiple bridging tables as well as SQL functions. But none is pulling the data as the date will not match or the item numbers dont match together from the 2 tables and a weird number pops up that is not correct because when i pull the data individual, they dont correspond